# Assert that actual value is in a collection of possible expected values

Tags: java, junit4, hamcrest

Is there a way to assert that an actual value equals any of a number of values?

Example:

```
String original = "...";
Collection<String> permittedTransformations = Set.of("...[1]", "...[2]", "...[3]");
String actual = transform(original);
assertThat(actual, isContainedIn(permittedTransformations));
```

I can see that I can just swap the arguments around:

```
assertThat(permittedTransformations, contains(actual));
```

but that reverses the semantics. I'm not checking if `permittedTransformations` is correct; I'm checking `actual`.

Comment: hamcrest has matchers `in()` and `oneOf()` which can be combined with `is()`, so you can write: `is(in(permittedTransformations))`

Comment: @SergeiTonoian thanks, I couldn't find `in()` but I found the similarly named `org.hamcrest.collection.IsIn.isIn()` instead, which is exactly what I was looking for. I hadn't found it before because I was only looking in CoreMatchers.

Comment: I was probably checking documentation for the latest version, but yeah you can use isIn()  as well, idk what version you are using though, but right now it's depreceted

Comment: @SergeiTonoian thanks for letting me know about the deprecation, I was indeed using an older version in our legacy codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the set elements to individual `Matcher<String>` objects, and combine them with `either`:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.reducing;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.either;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

Collection<String> permittedTransformations = Set.of("...[1]", "...[2]", "...[3]");
Optional<Matcher<String>> matcher = permittedTransformations.stream()
                                        .map(s -> is(s))
                                        .collect(reducing((m1, m2) -> either(m1).or(m2)));
assertThat(actual, matcher.get());
```

Comment: Thanks. Using `reduce` with `either` is a great idea, though I've just discovered `org.hamcrest.collection.IsIn.isIn()` which is really what I was looking for. But I'll keep your idea in mind for future use.